# No thank you after successful payment in paypal?

Tags: android, paypal

I have Integrated paypal in my Android App. I have Tested it in sandbox.It transfers the Money.It is working as expected. The problem is that it is not showing any thank you screen after successful payment. 
Thanks for your help 
[image]

Here's my code

```
public class Donate extends MainActivity
{
    EditText amount;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
    // Start with mock environment. When ready, switch to sandbox
    // (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
    // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)

            .clientId("ARUADxBbjYlJ7NQhY1Kqmo_8mwUoZHXKswj8Yl4ouFudB5MunhnRiZwHQ0dR");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.donate);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed)
    {
        // PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
        // Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only
        // authorize payment and
        // capture funds later.
        amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amtdon);
        BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal(amount.getText().toString());

        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amt, "USD", "Donate Remote IT ", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                    // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                    // see
                    // https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                    // for more details.

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        }
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
        {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thank-you screen was eliminated a while ago.  We plan to add a lighter weight indication that the payment was successfully completed (like a toast).